# YOLO5 : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.datasets'

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo, modulenotfounderror, yolov5

I am running a Yolo5 docker and want to import the `train.py` file in the yolov5 repository to my code. The structure of my files is as follows:

[image: files structure]

when I create the docker image and run `main_train.py` as follows :

main_train.py:

```
from yolov5 import train
```

I get this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main_train.py", line 1, in <module>
from yolov5 import train
File "/code/yolov5/train.py", line 40, in <module>
import val  # for end-of-epoch mAP
File "/code/yolov5/val.py", line 37, in <module>
from models.common import DetectMultiBackend
File "/code/yolov5/models/common.py", line 24, in <module>
from utils.dataloaders import exif_transpose, letterbox
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.dataloaders'
yolov5-train exited with code 1
```

Help to fix it.

Comment: do you have this module installed from the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.dataloaders'`

Comment: This is not a module to install(as always with pip ), It's just a directory in yolov5 folder.

Comment: @AliAminiBagh `yolov5` is a module within `train` directory. You can't import this way

Comment: @JeruLuke
This could be true probably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just happened to me. It turns out I had a module named `utils` already installed. Checking where it is with `utils.__file__` allowed me to identify where it comes from. Turns out it was installed by the game Endgame: Singularity. Purged the game and it now imports fine.